# Jquery Fadein toggle keep flickering (using wordpress)

Tags: jquery, css, hover, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress blog and have used the 'really simple facebook twitter share buttons ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons/ )

In the settings, i have selected to view the share icons below the post and i have a entry-footer. The plugin actually places the icons above the entry-footer so i've had to absolute position them and move them down.

I wanted an effect that the icons are hidden and then when the user hovers over the share text (or the entry-footer itself) the icons appear as a fadeIn/fadeOut effect. I have all this sorted however with the icons absolute positioned when the user hovers over the icons themselves the colour on the share text fades and the icons flicker. I have added a padding around the share and entry footer so if the user enters the mouse anywhere near here the icons appear but when the user is going over the icons, obviously the jQuery thinks that they have left this area and is fading out. If anyone can help me with this issue i would be grateful.

Here is the code for support:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
   $('.entry-footer').mouseover(function() {
     $('.really_simple_share').fadeToggle(400);
   });
 });
```

css:

```
.entry-footer a{
  height:88px;
}

h1.share a{
  padding:30px 560px 40px 30px;
  float:left;
}

.entry-footer a:hover {
  color:#79b74c;
}

.really_simple_share {
    position:absolute;
    margin:44px 0px 0px 140px;
    display:none;
}
```

I've also posted a question on here regarding to the issue with the icons on being top and bottom of post and not being able to move within the footer: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/social-icons-showing-twice-in-posts?replies=1#post-3994811

Answer (score 0):

You trigger a fadeToggle when ever you hover over the object. Which means if your mouse stays on it will keep fading.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
   $('.entry-footer').hover(function() {
     $('.really_simple_share').fadeIn(400);
   },
   function(){
     $('.really_simple_share').fadeOut(400);
   });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes it worse :(. I've tried hover, mouseenter/mouseover ect.I have an inkling that it's as the social icons are positioned over the entr-footer as they are not embedded within this file. (the link at the bottom of my post is currently asking if there is a way to do this with this plugin.). Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: I've fixed half of this by changing the class(entry-footer) in the jQuery to .share a, this doesn't flicker now i just need to sort out the colour of the share text.

Comment: You might post your HTML to else i can't really do anything.